# How to build nuget package from Script# projet

Tags: continuous-integration, nuget, nuget-package, script#

I need to build nuget package for Script# project

1) The package must include js files generated by Script#
2) It would be great to have auto increment for package version 
3) It must run on build server as part of continuous integration process

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is appeared easier than I thought

1. You will need to create mypackage.nuspec file
2. You need to specify your js files in files section

> ```
> <files>
>     <file src="bin\Release\some.js" target="Content\Scripts\some.js" />
> </files>
> ```

1. On your build server you need to run

> nuget pack mypackage.nuspec -Version 1.0.0.1

Replace 1.0.0.1 with incremental build version generated by your build system